# Can you force Parallel.Invoke to use multiple threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am using the task parallel library like this in a .aspx page:

```
 Parallel.Invoke(
                new Action[]
                    {
                        () => { users= service.DoAbc(); },
                        () => { products= service.DoDef(); }
                    });
```

Previously I was firing off a thread per call, and it was more responsive that it is now when I use Parallel.Invoke.

Should I assume the TPL library will do what's best or is there a way for me to tweak it so it actually does calls in parallel?

I guess it comes down to the type of hardware my website is running on, which I believe is a VM.

Each of my calls makes a http request to fetch results from a API call.

Comment: It will do that in parallel. Not sure why you're seeing a slowdown. BTW you can simplify that to `Parallel.Invoke(() => { users= service.DoAbc(); }, () => { products= service.DoDef(); });`

Comment: Do you try setting parallel options like this:

ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions(); 
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1; 

Parallel.Invoke(options, ...);

Comment: It already does use multiple threads.

Comment: MSDN says it MAY perform the options in parallel, its not guaranteed.

Answer (score 5):

Parallel.Invoke will run you methods in parallel unless this is more expensive than running them sequentially, or there are no available threads in the threadpool.This is an optimization, not an issue. Under normal circumstances you shouldn't try to second-guess the framework and just let it do its job.

You should consider overriding this behavior if you want to invoke some long-running IO-bound methods. Parallel.Invoke uses the default TaskScheduler which uses about as many threads as there are cores (not sure how many) to avoid overloading the CPU. This is not an issue if your actions just wait for some IO or network call to complete.

You can specify the maximum number of threads using the Parallel.Invoke(ParallelOptions,Action[])][1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.aspx) override. You  can also use the [ParallelOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.aspx) class to pass a cancellation token or specifiy a custom TaskScheduler, eg one that allows you to use more threads than the default scheduler.

You can rewrite your code like this:

```
Parallel.Invoke(
            new ParallelOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism=30},
            new Action[]
                {
                    () => { users= service.DoAbc(); },
                    () => { products= service.DoDef(); }
                });
```

Still, you should not try to modify the default options unless you find an actual performance problem. You may end up oversubscribing your CPU and causing delays or thrashing.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer and generally what the OP should be doing, however the question is specifically asking how to guarantee that they are run on different threads.  Perhaps you could add a method that you can be sure will actually run the methods on two different threads in the event he really is in the case you describe in your last paragraph.

Comment: That's what the custom TaskScheduler is for. Besides, I've used similar code with Parallel.ForEach to query 2000 servers, 100 at a time. Unless there is a real reason to force the use of different threads, it's better to use the default behavior

Comment: Yes, as I said before, it is generally best to use the default behavior, but the OP is specifically saying that he's using the default behavior, doesn't want to do that, and wants to ensure that each operation has a dedicated thread.  While it's perfectly appropriate to state that that's unlikely to be needed, it's also important to actually answer the question in the event that it really is needed.

Answer (score 2):

You could fire off a couple tasks to handle the calls.

```
// Change to Task.Factory.StartNew depending on .NET version
var userTask = Task.Run(() => service.DoAbc());
var productsTask = Task.Run(() => service.DoDef());

Task.WaitAll(userTask, productsTask);

users = userTask.Result;
products = productsTask.Result;
```

Comment: That will use the thread pool, which may very well only have one thread in it, so even this isn't guaranteed to run them in different threads.  You'll need to actually new up two threads if you want to be *sure*.  Of course, the power of all of these parallelization frameworks is that most people really don't need as many threads as they think they do, so barring exceptional circumstances it's better to let them work it out.

Comment: @Servy perhaps you are interpreting the question too literally. Yes, there is a chance that if you use the ThreadPool you will have to wait for an available thread if the ThreadPool is exhausted. If that happens though, you have already created far too many threads.

You can instruct the framework to use more threads by passing the TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning option when spawning a new Task.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Not only is there a chance it'll need to wait for an available thread, there's a very high chance, particularly with this exact code.  The thread pool, by default, will only have one thread in it, and I would imagine that this code wouldn't be utilizing it for long enough to result in a second being created.  I'd say it's *likely* that only one thread will execute both of these methods.